# Django extending user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-rest-framework

I have a model called Farmer which extends 'User' plus it has some additional attributes like birth date, telephone number etc.

How can I use User's attribute such as first_name, last_name to refer in Farmer model? Or maybe How I can show them on my admin interface in Farmer table? I do not want to have first_name, last_name again in my Farmer model as it's a repetition. Essentially Farmer is also a user who will have same first_name & last_name.

I tried following which gives me  `"Field 'first_name' doesn't have a default value"` error when I try to add new farmer.

```
class Farmer(models.Model):
 user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True) 
 birth_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
 address = models.TextField(max_length=500)
 phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
 phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], blank=True, max_length=20) # validators should be a list

 #This helps to print in admin interface as e.g. Thomas the farmer, without this in admin interface you see farmer object which is difficult to distinguish
 def __str__(self):
    print(self.user.first_name)              # __unicode__ on Python 2
    return "%s" % (self.user)
```

My admin.py

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('id','username' ,'email', 'is_active', 'date_joined', 'is_staff','last_login', )

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

admin.site.register(Farmer)
```

Comment: When does this error happen, during migration or while creating a new farmer?

Comment: While creating a new farmer, migration was successful. I then deleted all the existing users, created new super user and created one user afterwards.

Comment: The `User` you are referencing in your Model, is that the `django.contrib.auth.User`? And do you create the new user via UserAdmin or via FarmerAdmin?

Comment: Yes it's django.contrib.auth.User. I created one user via default API hitting rest-auth/registration and in admin interface I tried creating a farmer which threw error. In admin interface for Farmer I can see a drodown which collects all the users.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: Actually after a bit of a discussion with my colleagues I moved away from trying to get User attributes in Farmer model, but we decided to instead go for custom user model where we store user type as 'Farmer' for User. So I changed my codebase pretty extensively, and could not really try your solution. However I should say thanks for it, and I will try it for sure with a dummy model.

Comment: I just realized I did the same thing in my new codebase with some different model and it works perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really easy to get related models to appear in a list display but involves a bit of typing.

```
class FarmerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_username(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_is_staff(self):
        return self.user.is_staff

    list_display = (get_username, get_is_staff, .... )

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super(FarmerAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).select_related('user')
```

note that the modification to the queryset is required otherwise each line in your admin list view will result in a query. your `__str__` method has the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Class Farmer(User):

This will make is work

Comment: This essentially removed Farmer from my admin interface and instead gave a link to Users again which has attributes of both User and farmer. That's not what I want.